# Incomplete message from the response

Tags: wcf, app-config

I have a wcf service and I am trying to call it from other client, but the response I am getting as a reply is incomplete. It stops from the

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

        if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            Log.Debug("VisService SOAP Response >>>");
            //create a copy of the response for logging purpose
            MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();
            //log the copy to avoid removal of the actual response object
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message replyCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms);
            replyCopy.WriteMessage(writer);
            //move the position of the cursor to the begining to
            //read the entire message from start
            ms.Position = 0;
            string visServiceSOAPResponse = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8).ReadLine();
            Log.Debug(visServiceSOAPResponse);
            //For displaying the message in the mail confirmation box
            SaveResponseToLog("\nVisService SOAP Response >>>\n" + visServiceSOAPResponse);
        }   
    }

    //This function logs the SOAP 
    //request in the application log file
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            string visServiceSOAPRequest = request.ToString();
            Log.Debug("VisService SOAP Request >>>");
            Log.Debug(visServiceSOAPRequest);
            //For displaying the message in the mail confirmation box
            SaveResponseToLog("\nVisService SOAP Request >>>\n" +     visServiceSOAPRequest);
        }
        return null;
    }        
}
```

and the response from the wcf is only till the "...xmlns="

Answer (score 0):

Your log writing function is buggy. Please scrap it alltogether. Use [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143357(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) if you want to append text to a file.

In addition, you seem to read only the first line of the response. You need to read the whole response before writing it to the file.

Edit:

Your log function has too many bugs and weird things to actually fix it. Replace it with:

```
private void SaveResponseToLog(string msg)
{
  System.IO.File.AppendAllText(filename, msg, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: private void SaveResponseToLog(string msg)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = null;
            //StreamReader rd = null;
            
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                File.Exists(filename);
            }
            else if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                writer = System.IO.File.AppendText(filename);
                writer.Write(msg);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
            else{}
                    }

Comment: Can you tell me in deatil which you refering to? I had changed that also to to ReadToEnd()